# App Virtualization of Eclipse application

Tags: eclipse, migration, internet-explorer-6, virtualization, appv

I have Eclipse running several widgets on Windows XP. I believe that the widgets will only work on IE6, so I want to use App-V (or similar) to encapsulate [Eclipse + widgets + IE6] into an executable and run it on Windows 8/10.

Is this a workable solution or should I be looking elsewhere?

p.s. This is just a 'stopgap' measure, but the eventual recode might take years to complete...

Comment: Is this is your quistion?

Comment: my question is will it work? using app-v to virtualize the eclipse running on Xp